# Lua websockets for heka

Tags: lua, websocket, hekad

I am using lua-websockets https://github.com/lipp/lua-websockets to try and get a web socket server running.

Using the copas example they provided:

```
local copas = require'copas'

local server = require'websocket'.server.copas.listen
{

  port = 8080,

  protocols = {
    echo = function(ws)
      while true do
        local message = ws:receive()
        if message then
           ws:send(message)
        else
           ws:close()
           return
        end
      end
    end
  }
}

copas.loop()
```

This works and starts listening on port 8080 and I am able to connect and get a echo response back.

The problem is when I try and integrate it with heka. I start heka and it starts the websocket server but hangs at Loading plugin. When it tries to "load" a plugin, it executes the lua script.

Now my question is, how do I run the websocket server and send a "success" to heka to let it continue start up. Simply this would be: if the websocket is listening on 8080 return to heka and say the lua script has been executed successfully.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `copas.loop()` as it enters an indefinite loop that handles all copas socket interactions. You need to use `copas.step()` instead (see [controlling copas](http://keplerproject.github.io/copas/manual.html#control) section) and call it at the appropriate time from your heka code (this call will return `false` on timeout and `true` when it handles something). In a GUI application it may be called from an IDLE handler.